# Do we have any sample ui integration tests for vscode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write e2e integration tests for a vscode extension. I didn't find any ui integration tests. Can you please provide me the links if any

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [extensions/vscode-api-tests/src/singlefolder-tests/editor.test.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/vscode-api-tests/src/singlefolder-tests/editor.test.ts) in the vscode sources as a starting point for integration tests.  If that particular test isn't quite what you want, there are a bunch of tests adjacent to it that might be.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670483/2659307) I gave to a related question about using the API from within tests.